# Javascript form validation error

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Form Validation </title>
<style type="text/css">
fieldset { width: 280px; padding: 6px; }
label { float: left; width: 100px; font: 12px Arial; padding: 5px; }
input { margin-bottom: 5px; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form id="inputForm" onsubmit="return validateForm();" action="#">
<fieldset>
    <label>First Name:</label><input type="text" name="first_name" /><br />
    <label>Surname:</label><input type="text" name="surname" /><br />
    <label>Postcode:</label><input type="text" name="postcode" /><br />
    <label>Email:</label><input type="text" name="email" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send form" />
    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
</fieldset>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
    var form = document.forms['inputForm'];
    var formats = {
        First_name: /^[a-z]+[\-`\s]?[a-z]+$/i, 
        Surname: /^[a-z]+[\-`\S]?[a-z]+$/i, 
        Postcode: /^\d{4}$/, 
        Email:/^w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/ 
    };

    var elCount = form.elements.length;
    for(var i = 0; i <elCount; i++) {
        var field = form.elements[i];
        if(field.type == 'text') {
            if(!formats[field.name].test(field.value)) {
                alert('Invalid '+field.name.replace('_', ' '));
                field.focus();
                return false;
            }
    }
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hey guys trying to figure out why the code is giving me a error:underfinded formats[fields.Name] but its has been defined. Its just a simple form so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Sorry for the basic question but I have been looking over it multiple time and can't see it. Cheers again.

Comment: Can you show us the HTML source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the error you are talking about is on this line:

```
if(!formats[field.Name].test(field.value)) {
```

I'd suggest using a lowercase "n" in the "name" property:

```
if(!formats[field.name].test(field.value)) {
```

JavaScript is case sensitive.

UPDATE: In addition to what I've already mentioned, but still regarding case sensitivity, your `formats` object has property names with mixed case, e.g., `First_name`, but the corresponding input elements have a `name` attribute in lowercase, e.g., `name="first_name"`, so when you retrieve an element's `name` and try to use it to look up the property in `formats` it will return `undefined`. You need to make those match case.

Fix those errors and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/M4Nzr/